# Xamarin forms show progress circle in modal

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

[image: Modal with Circle wait cursor]

I want a modal like this image as a wait cursor. Here, when clicking next, a white modal appears with a circle moving inside it.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [ProgressRingPlugin](https://github.com/AndreasHennig/ProgressRingPlugin)?

Comment: @adamm thanks for your comment but my problem is to show the popup page not only the progress circle. I also can't figure out how to work with 
Rg.Plugins.Popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs).

When you want display the circle loading progress,you just need call it:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("");
```

the effect like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Leo Zhu for your help. Fortunately, I found a better solution. Please see my answer. It does not depend on any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

this is awesome: https://github.com/suneelbiyyapu/DisplayPopUp

I just add the gif in this project and everything is fine. thanks, **Suneel**.

[image]

And Successfully added into my project:
[image: Implemented on my app]